# Обфускатор js на php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

В интернете есть сервисы обфускации js кода в вид типа

`var _0x87b8=["\x74\x65\x73\x74"];alert(_0x87b8[0]);`

так вот, возможно ли сделать php функцию для такой обфускации? Я имею ввиду не алгоритм обфускации, а просто что бы он возвращал результат обфускации js библиотеки? Функция нужна для обфускации кода в реальном времени. то есть код js всегда меняется и функция будет срабатывать при каждом посещении страницы.

Comment: "Я имею ввиду не алгоритм обфускации" - Вы именно это и имеете ввиду

Comment: @windirprog, гуглите "полиморфный обфускатор", ну или "polymorphic obfuscator", если я правильно понял задачу. Как вариант - взять готовые исходники какого-нибудь обфускатора и добавить в них разбавление кода случайным шумом.

Могу ещё добавить, что на тему полиморфной обфускации есть несколько серьёзных академических исследований, но они представляют лишь теоретический интерес. Потому как в реальном мире эти извращения нафиг никому не нужны.

--------

P.S. Я исхожу из того, что вы НЕ имели в виду "обфускатор javascript на PHP", потому как такая простейшая задача выгугливается в один клик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> возможно ли сделать php функцию для
> такой обфускации?

Попробуйте так:

```
function str2hex($str){
  $hex = '';
  for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++){
    $hex .= '\x'.dechex(ord($str[$i]));
  }
  return $hex;
}
str2hex('hello'); // результат: \x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f
```

Comment: @windirprog, "Генератор js" - это как? Вы хотите это же написать на JS?

Comment: @Deonis, если немного переварить, то получается, что человеку нужен просто обфускатор, через который он будет прогонять свой JS перед отдачей клиенту.